# Is there way to authenticate to Graph API using Username and Password without Application Registration in Azure AD

Tags: c#, azure, authentication

I'm creating an app that needs to authenticate to multiple Office 365 applications in differing tenants using the Graph API. If I follow Microsoft's guidance I can do this, but I have to register the app in each new Azure AD which adds quite a lot of overhead for the user. I'd like to be able to avoid this step and use a username and password only in the authentication provider. This is the link to the Microsoft page which gives example code: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS#usernamepassword-provider

Thanks

Nathan

Answer (score 4):

**Is there way to authenticate to Graph API using Username and Password without Application Registration in Azure AD?**

> To access the data in Microsoft Graph, your application will need to
>   acquire an OAuth 2.0 access token. To achieve access token you must need
>   application Id.No way to bypass it.

Unfortunately, You have to register an App for accessing `Microsoft Graph API` resources. Because Graph API requires `ApplicationId`, `Application Secret` to authenticate request. In that case you have no other options.  Its a application architecture.

As you may know, to use Graph API you need to use any of the [authentication grant flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/authentication-scenarios) provided by Microsoft. If you seen the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/authentication-scenarios) you would know that each of the application at least need to have `application Id` which Graph API uses to trace the request is for.

For more details you can have a look [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/best-practices-concept?view=graph-rest-1.0#authentication)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I’d thought as much. Thanks again, Nathan

Answer (score 0):

You need your application registration to get the **ClientID** and **TenantID** and the permissions to use the Graph API, but you could use without the token with user and password.

With this (max) combination of Libraries (You could not use the 3 first):

> Azure.Core 1.24.0
> Azure.Identity                    1.6.0
> Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces 6.0.0
> Microsoft.Graph                   3.35.0
> Microsoft.Graph.Auth          1.0.0 Preview 7 
> Microsoft.Graph.Core          1.25.1
> Microsoft.Identity.Client     4.39.0
> Microsoft.Identity.Client.Extensions.Msal     2.19.3

Just because Microsoft.Graph.Auth is deprecated (No more updates)

```
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Graph.Auth;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using System.Security;
```

In the function you are goint to work you could use:
GraphServiceClient graphClient = await CreateGraphClient();

To set your password (with or without the static):

```
public static SecureString Password
        {
            get
            {
                var password = "xxxxxxxxx";
                if (password.StartsWith("Error."))
                    throw new InvalidProgramException(password);
                SecureString secPass = new SecureString();
                password.ToCharArray().ToList().ForEach(secPass.AppendChar);
                secPass.MakeReadOnly();
                return secPass;
            }
        }

internal static string UserName { get; } = "Usuario";
```

And you could define (with or without the static) the function as:

```
internal static async Task<GraphServiceClient> CreateGraphClient()
        {
            var pass = Password;
            IPublicClientApplication publicClientApplication = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
                                   .Create(ClientID)
                                   .WithTenantId(TenantID)
                                   .Build();
            UsernamePasswordProvider authProvider = new UsernamePasswordProvider(publicClientApplication);
            GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);
            try
            {
                User usr = await graphClient.Me.Request().WithUsernamePassword(UserName, pass).GetAsync();
            }
            catch {
                throw;
            }
            return graphClient;
        }
```